Is there a way to use a more precise "number" implementation in JavaScript in GraalJS?
I have a Java application where the user can write (mostly simple) JavaScripts to define how to calculate certain numbers. In Java those numbers are BigDecimal to avoid floating point inaccuracies.
I want to mimic the behaviour of BigDecimal in JavaScript without the user having to know anything about it.
Ideally I want a simple scipt which is evaluated in GraalJS that looks like this
var x = 0.1;
var y = 0.2;
var z = x + y;
z;

to return 0.3 (and not 0.3000000004) and not having to change the syntax.
I tried using BigDecimals themself to mitigate the inaccuracies, which works fine but requires to change the syntax.
In addition to that I used operator overloading which at least simplified the calculation part, but the variables would still need to be explicitly created as BigDecimal (with Operator Overloading):
var x = new BigDecimalWithOperatorOverloading(0.1);
var y = new BigDecimalWithOperatorOverloading(0.2);
var z = x + y;
z;


=> returns 0.3

Next I looked into defining a proxy for number, which did not work:
const globalProxy = new Proxy(globalThis, {
    set(target, prop, value) {
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            value = new BigDecimalWithOperatorOverloading(value);
        }
        target[prop] = value;
        return true;
    },
    get(target, prop) {
        return target[prop];
    }
});


const originalPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(globalThis);

var x = 0.1;

=> typeof x is number (should be BigDecimalWithOperatorOverloading)

